# Can SharePoint servers in a farm be a mix of Server 2008 SP2 and Server 2008 R2?

Tags: 2010, windows-server

We just found out that our server team built some servers with 2008 SP2 and some with 2008 R2. Is this going to cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is supported by Microsoft and I have seen multiple environments with a mixed OS setup. For example, during the transition to 64-bit with SharePoint 2007, it was fairly common for customers to split the upgrade into tiers, often starting with the SQL tier.

As long as the individual servers meet the [minimum requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) I can't see it being a big issue.

If you are deploying customisations you may see inconsistencies between servers due to differences in the underlying OS, and from a configuration standpoint you may find that security changes etc. lead to additional administration overhead.

If Microsoft don't support a mixed OS setup that otherwise meets the minimum requirements I would be surprised and interested to know why.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky since there is a difference between "causing problems" and "is supported by Microsoft".

First: It is not recommended to mix different OS's in one farm. If you can change it with reasonable effort, I would do it.

Second: If it is not possible to change the OS, at least make sure that every server role (like WFE, SQL, APP) has the same OS. It is not supported to mix OS within a role.

Third: If you have a problem with your farm and ask MS support to help, they will kindly please you to re-produce that issue on a farm with servers that have the same OS.

BTW: Troubleshooting errors caused by mixed OS is -let's say- ...interesting!

Comment: Is the "do not mix different OS's" recommendation documented somewhere?

Comment: I haven't found it yet. It has been a statement from our MS support technican.

Comment: If someone finds a statement that mixing OS's *within a role* is supported I'd like to delete my answer as it might be obsolete.